# Redux key based array not triggering new props when added to 2nd time

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I am dealing with **Proposals** and locations.
A **location** can have multiple **proposals**.

The component is passed a location object (below as *passedProps*) to show all the proposals for this location :

`<Proposals location={ location } key={location.id}/>`

Here is are my redux props :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state , passedProps) => {
  return {
    proposals : state.propertyProposals[passedProps.location.id]
  };
};
```

when adding a new proposal, I want to store their ids by location, so in a addition to storing the proposal, I am storing their Ids, in an array keyed by location Id.

The first proposal added and refreshed with new props just fine, however even though the second one is successfully pushed to the array, this is not triggering new props, so it does not "refresh" -- If I leave the route and come back I see the new 2nd proposal (which did not show the first time)

Here is the PROPOSAL_CREATE action for a new Proposal.

```
 type :'PROPOSAL_CREATE',
 payload :
{'e7ef104e-19ed-acc8-7db5-8f13839faae3' : { 
    id : 'e7ef104e-19ed-acc8-7db5-8f13839faae3',
    locationId: '41e9c5d8-a520-7e3b-939a-12f784d49712'
    }
}
```

here is the case which handles it :

```
case 'PROPOSAL_CREATE':
{
  const proposal = Object.values(action.payload)[0];
  const locationId = proposal.locationId;
  let newState = {...state}
    if (locationId in newState) {
        newState[locationId].push(proposal.id)
    } else {
        newState[locationId] = [proposal.id]
    }

    return newState
}
```

Is there an obvious reason I am not seeing the change in the component for the second entry?

Thanks

Comment: did you specify action type?

Comment: yes, I originally included the payload only in my question. Works both times, just does not get new props the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one issue here. Your store state is not immutable. You have used below line to make a copy:

```
let newState = {...state}
```

Here it does make copy of object but it's shallow copy, hence your array object in `newState` and `state` have the same reference. That's why redux doesn't identify the change in store and hence props are not updated in sequence.

You can clone your state by below methods:

```
let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

OR if you use jQuery then:

```
let newState = $.extend(true, {}, state);
```

I think this will surely fix your issue.

Comment: Yes this worked! I thought the spread operator ...state was doing the same. however  json parse/stringify shocks me as hacky. We have a JS object and need to convert it to a string and then back to a js object to achieve this!!! I tried Object.assign({}, state) and it also did not work. I guess Google needs to get to  work! Thanks again

Comment: `Object.assign({}, state)` also creates shallow copy. Cloning has to deep copy and JSON parse/stringify is safe option for it. Also in `$.extend(true, {}, state)` first parameter is for deep cloning and we have passed it a `true`, so it does perform a deep cloning on object. Also you can use immutable JS with redux store to prevent such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reducer logic i think that you did not specify action type.

The one of the redux conventions is the action recognition based on `type` property.
I bet that you forgot to specify that property.

```
var properAction = {
        type: 'PROPOSAL_CREATE',
        payload: {
            {
                'e7ef104e-19ed-acc8-7db5-8f13839faae3': {
                    id: 'e7ef104e-19ed-acc8-7db5-8f13839faae3',
                    locationId: '41e9c5d8-a520-7e3b-939a-12f784d49712'
                }
            }
        }
```

I would recommend you to write [action creators](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators) it will reduce your place for typos like that.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but nope, i gave the action payload, the type is fine... And as I said It "refreshes" with new props the first time successfully but not the second, even though it is in fact stored

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. I forgot that *Arrays* of an original *object* are still by *reference*. So even after

`let newState = {...state}`

`newState[locationId]`
has the same reference as 
`state[locationId]`

2. As a result my original statement was mutating the original state, not creating a newState

and so 
`newState[locationId].push(proposal.id)`

needed to be

```
newState[locationId] = state[locationId].concat(proposal.id);
```

or es6

```
newState[locationId] = [ ...state[locationId] , proposal.id ] ;
```